# Recursively group a java 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, dictionary, 2d

I have a 2D array of my game's map. The array contains 1's or 0's.
A map could look like this, for instance:

```
11111111111
10000000001
10000011001
10000111001
10000011001
10000000001
11111111111
```

Is there any way to group the 1's that are touching into separate arrays so that I can turn them into generalpaths later?